# Bison: expression malfunction

Tags: bison

I over this problem all day and I cannot figure what is wrong..

Let's say I have this code:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    extern int error;
    extern int yylineno;
    extern char *yytext;    
    int errors      = 0;
%}
%start main_struct

%token INT  1
%token COMMA    2
%token LEFT_PARENTHESIS 3
%token RIGHT_PARENTHESIS 4
%token K_BEGIN  5
%token END  6

%%
main_struct:    functions_declaration
        ;

functions_declaration: function
                     | functions_declaration function
                     ;

function: data_type identifier1 LEFT_PARENTHESIS vars_in_func RIGHT_PARENTHESIS
          K_BEGIN function_body END;

vars_in_func:       /*empty*/ 
            | vars_in_f
            ;

vars_in_f:      data_type identifier1
            | vars_in_f COMMA data_type identifier1
            ;

function_body:      /*empty*/ 
                        ;

data_type:  INT
            ;
identifier1:    IDENTIFIER
        | identifier1 COMMA IDENTIFIER
        ;

%%

int main ()
{     
  if (yyparse() == 0 && error==0){
     printf("Accepted\n");
   }
  else{
     printf("Rejected\n");
   }
}
yyerror(char *s){
    printf ("%s:at line %d\n", s,yylineno);
    errors++;
}
```

When I try it on this expression : int foo( int x, int y) begin end

it recognize "int" "foo" "(" then report that there is an error. Why is unacceptable?

Comment: @Victory Sorry if I was not clear. My grammar supposed to recognize all the line <int foo(int x, int y)> But instead it recognize the first 3 tokens only. int foo and ( then throws error.. But I cannot figure out why it does that

Comment: Yes, it would be good to see the text/output of the error.

Comment: @Victory There is not an actual error but it is unacceptable. An output would be like:


Token KEYWORD : int
Token IDENTIFIER : foo
Token LEFT PARENTHESIS : (

Then it stops

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `vars_in_func` and `vars_in_f` with this:

```
func_params:
    /* empty */
  | param_list
  ;

param_list:
    data_type identifier1
  | param_list COMMA data_type identifier1
  ;
```

Obviously I've changed the naming a little (which you'll need to coordinate with your definition of `function`). And I don't understand your definition of `identifier1` since it allows multiple identifiers separated by commas, which doesn't make sense to me in this context.

Comment: This will accept some sentences that must not be accepted. Like: int foo(,int x) since param_list can be empty. But even so with this does not recognize even this int foo(int x). I really cannot understand why..

Comment: @Manos I don't understand why you think `param_list` can be empty. It certainly isn't defined that way in my answer. At any rate, you should edit your question to show your current code, and include everything so that someone can run it.

Comment: I changed my question and submit additional code. Yes you are correct your code is acceptable. But yet, it cannot recognize the submitted code  >>int foo(int x)<<  . Concerning the identifier I am now trying to learn about Bison so for the moment I will leave it as it is. But I cannot understand why does not recognize the second int by the time it has already recognize the first one.

Comment: @Manos I don't understand what you're up to. How can you compile it without defining `IDENTIFIER`? And where's your lexer?